# Initiate automatic commands in screen (Linux)

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I want to initiate those commands automatically when attaching a screen:

Ctrl+a |

Then

Ctrl+a TAB

Then

Ctrl+a :resize 15

Anyway to do this in one command line?

Answer (score 1):

You can put respective commands at the end of your `~/.screenrc` file and they'll get executed every time you start screen. In case you'd like this happen only occasionally, you could create a special screenrc-file, e.g. `~/.screenrc.special` and then run screen with `screen -c ~/.screenrc.special` when you want these things to happen.

Your `~/.screenrc` in this case should have as last three lines this:

```
split
focus
resize 15
```

Comment: I want a "Vertical split", not a horizontal one. And how do you specify which window you want to resize? I want to resize Window 1 not 0.

Comment: Another problem is that the "Two windows" created from split is not there anymore when deattaching - reattaching the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Split now supports the -v option

```
split -v
focus
resize 15
```